# How to get the index of a pivot table as columns

Tags: python, indexing, pivot-table

I'm trying to pivot a table that I have.  It has 4 main columns, and about 20 other columns of no use.  The columns are Site, Category, Week_Beginning and Total_Hours.

I'm trying to sum the total_hours by site, category and week_beginning.

I'm using the `df.pivot_table` function, and it does it as I want, but the output needs some fixing.

It works well, but I get the following output:

> Index                                              ('sum','Total_Hours')
>   ('Site1','Cat1',Timestamp('2019-12-23'))                  725

The code I'm using is:

```
df2=df.pivot_table(index=['Site','Category','Week_Beginning'],values=['Total_Hours'],aggfunc=[np.sum],fill_value=0)
```

The code works well from a math perspective, that is to say, that the sum is correct

The output is:

It works well, but I get the following output:

> Index                                              ('sum','Total_Hours')
>   ('Site1','Cat1',Timestamp('2019-02-23'))                  725

So the output only has one column with a name of ('sum','Total_Hours')

What I was expecting was 4 columns as shown below:

```
Site       Category           Week_Beginning           Total_Hours
Site1        Cat1               2019-03-23                225
Site1        Cat1               2019-03-30                152
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I'm using python 3.7.3 via Spyder 3.3.3

Thanks.

-PR.

Comment: Why don't you use `groupby`? Pivot is a highly unusual function for this job.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should use `groupby` -

```
df2=df.groupby(['Site','Category','Week_Beginning']).agg({"Total_Hours":"sum"}).reset_index()
```